# Optional configuration and order of enable modules on profile

Tags: 8, configuration, installation-profiles

I have a bug or a misconfiguration I don't understand. I'm creating a profile to create new web sites with an advance configuration quickly. But I meet a bug during installation with dependencies of with some configurations.

On image style, I add a manual `crop type than I add on the majority image style. For example, my file for image style large is:

```
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - crop.type.crop_1x1
  module:
    - crop
name: large
label: 'Large (480×480)'
effects:
  ddd73aa7-4bd6-4c85-b600-bdf2b1628d1d:
    uuid: ddd73aa7-4bd6-4c85-b600-bdf2b1628d1d
    id: image_scale
    weight: -9
    data:
      width: 480
      height: 480
      upscale: false
  7cd03233-541d-472e-851c-de8945ee6709:
    uuid: 7cd03233-541d-472e-851c-de8945ee6709
    id: crop_crop
    weight: -10
    data:
      crop_type: crop_1x1
```

I put all images style configuration file in the directory `optional` in `config` directory. My configuration files for crop and the crop type are in the `install` directory. Despite this, when I test my installation, I have always the error message :

> Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects provided by image have unmet dependencies: image.style.large (crop.type.crop_1x1, crop) in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create() (line 98 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php).

I have no configuration which are dependent of `image` module in `install` directory. `Image` module is always enable before `Crop` module instead of to respect dependencies. I tried to put my configuration files for crop in optional but it doesn't fix the problem, I don't know if change the order of modules in dependencies of my profile have an influence. I try without success.

I don't see where is the error in my installation.

Update: This problem happens only with default configuration of `image` module, that is `image.style.large`, `image.style.medium` and `image.style.thumbnail` which are the native configuration. I have other styles which are import later, after `crop` module is enable and configure as expected. I don't know if it's a bug of the configuration manager which try to import necessary default configuration files even if they are in optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is a bug of the configuration system. An issue exists for this exact problem: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2922417